# Show Form depending on database condition

Tags: c#, wpf, database, conditional-statements

On initial startup of my application i am looking to check whether `Table` within my `Database` has any tuples within it, if this condition is true then i do not want my `addDialog` form to show however when it is false i would like to show it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I have tried:

```
private void Home_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //AddSafeLimits dialog = new AddSafeLimits();
    //dialog.Show();

    var query = from level in context.SafeLimits
                    where level.UpperLimit == null
                    select level;

    levels = query.ToList();

    if (levels== null)
    {
        AddSafeLimits dialog = new AddSafeLimits();
        dialog.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider showing what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think LINQ will return an empty instead of NULL
so you can try to use:

```
if (levels== null||levels.Count==0)
        {
            AddSafeLimits dialog = new AddSafeLimits();
            dialog.Show();
        }
```

Comment: Appreciate the reply. The dialog box is still not showing but I think it could be a problem with my query? any help would be great.

Comment: Set a break and check what is in your list `levels`